# How to delete parent+child nodes based on specific condition using python

Tags: python

**SAMPLE XML FILE**

```
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. abc@gmail.com</Affiliation>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>-</Affiliation>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. ghi@yahoo.co.in</Affiliation>
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

I want to delete all Articles whose <Affliation> has value **-**  . i.e whose Affliation looks like `<Affliation>-</Affliation>`

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. abc@gmail.com</Affiliation>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. ghi@yahoo.co.in</Affiliation>
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

Comment: How are you receiving this data, @yugamuppal? Is it a string?

Comment: It's a XML file and this is a sample data however the original data looks like the same @LuanNaufal

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: @YugamUppal, please consider accepting one of the provided answers if you are satisfied with any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will read the XML from `input.xml` and writes the modified document to `output.xml`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

dom = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = dom.getroot()

for article in root.findall('Article'):
    if article.find('Affiliation').text == '-':
        root.remove(article)

dom.write('output.xml')
```

**EDIT:** Using `lxml`, I am getting a significantly better performance (759 ms to process a file with 150,000 `<Article>` entries). Not sure if it will be fast enough for 15 million entries, though.

```
from lxml import etree

dom = etree.parse('input.xml')
root = dom.getroot()

for article in dom.xpath('Article[Affiliation="-"]'):
    root.remove(article)

dom.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: this code is very slow as i am having around 1.5crore articles in one XML file and this code is taking too much time which is not feasible

Comment: Please try out the `lxml` approach I added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you received this page as a string, and calling it html, you can use the following code to run your logic. The idea is to first gather the positions of your Articles tags, and after check if the tag "Affiliation" is comprised only of "-"

```
def removeFromText(html, tag, position):
    article = html[position[0]:position[1]]
    beginning = article.find("<" + tag + ">") + len("<" + tag + ">") + position[0]
    end = article.find("</" + tag + ">") + position[0]
    print(beginning, end)
    affiliation = html[beginning:end]
    print(affiliation)

    if beginning != -1 and html[beginning:end] == "-": 
        return html[:position[0]] + html[position[1]:] 
    return html

query = "Article"
start = 0
positions = []

while True:
    foundOpen = html.find("<"+query+">", start)
    if foundOpen == -1: break

    foundClose = html.find("</"+query+">", start) + len("</"+query+">")
    positions.append((foundOpen, foundClose))
    start = foundClose

for (opening,closing) in reversed(positions):
    print(opening, closing)
    html = removeFromText(html, "Affiliation", (opening,closing))
```

Now your `html` variable is storing the final information, after the filtering

Comment: This removes all `<Affiliation>` tags, regardless of what they contain and does not delete any `<Article>` tags. OP wants to _delete all Articles whose `<Affliation>` has value `-` . i.e whose Affliation looks like `<Affliation>-</Affliation>`_

Comment: You're right, @MartinFrodl, guess I didn't quite read the problem! Will reformulate